# Can I truncate log in simple recovery mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transaction, transaction-log

I have a few SQL Server 2005 databases in simple recovery mode. The disk volume in which my transaction logs are stored had only 1GB free, when I started a stored procedure (massive delete in a single table) the log grows a lot and the disk is running out of space, and the stored procedure seems to work indefinetly. How can I manage this transaction log?

Comment: Change the delete to run in batches instead of a single execution.  I usually go for deleting 10K records at a single shot.  Or if your stored procedure is using a date value for the delete, then walk the delete forward in time, deleting a day of data at a time.

Comment: I am using MSSQL2005. Unfortunately I cannot change the way this stored procedure is ran. I have already modified a parameter in order to delete the minimum amount of data.

Comment: Is the delete a "regular" thing you need to do, or is it just a one-off? I'm assuming as there is a SP then it's a regular thing (?) but please confirm.

Comment: It's not a regular thing, it's one shot. We need to perform one time bulk delete on a table that growed out of control.

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices:

1. Break the delete into chunks, as [Jonathan explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124716/can-i-truncate-log-in-simple-recovery-mode/124719#comment229552_124716) and as I blogged about here:

   - [Break large delete operations into chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)
2. Give the transaction log more space to grow to accommodate the log activity (and don't shrink it after every delete; all this does is make the next delete take longer). If you run a delete command that deletes 100K rows, the log has to be able to record all of that activity, regardless of recovery model.

For a much more thorough treatment of the subject, see:

- [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186)